# How to send a request to twitter using a proxy?

Tags: twitter, proxy, tweepy

I'm trying  to extract data from twitter. When I use the code in my home network, it works very well, but in my university we use a proxy server. So I need to configure the request. I'm not specialised on computer science, so I don't know how to modify the request. 
I read the documentation in https://dev.twitter.com/ but I couldn't find a solution!

This is an exemple of code :

```
 import tweepy
 from tweepy import OAuthHandler

 consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
 consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
 access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
 access_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

 auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
 auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

 api = tweepy.API(auth)

 for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(100):
     # Process a single status
       print(status.text)
```

This is the error I got:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\formation\python\github tools\fbp.py", line 14, in <module>
   for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(100):
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 197, in next
   self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py", line 108, in next
     data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args,             **self.kargs)
   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 189, in execute
   raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
 TweepError: Failed to send request:    HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with   url: /1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to    proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Authentification proxy requise',)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a proxy using the follow code:

```
api =tweepy.API(auth,proxy="127.0.0.1:1080")
```

It works on my computer. You can try to modify you code like this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of what you do? It does not solve the problem for me. Thanks